# Should Views result URL's be blocked in robots.txt?

Tags: views

I've a View of Jobs search depending on several exposed filters and I find plenty of url's like these in Google's index in the Google Webmaster Tools:

http://www.example.com/views/advanced-search?field_city_tid=&sort_by=field_last_date_of_application_value&sort_order=DESC&&&order=type&sort=desc

I see no point in indexing those URL's. Should I do block it in the robots.txt or make the result page "noindex" using Metatag module?

Comment: You raise a good question but the answer here seems obviously 'yes, these should be blocked' - is your question more as to how you would do this or why isn't this being done already?

Comment: Yes I'd like to ask both questions as well as knowing pros/cons of doing it.